# JavaFX - difference between modular and non-modular

Tags: java, javafx

At the moment I am reading the ['Getting started'](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) of JavaFX. It distinguishes modular and non-modular approaches.

For example among 'JavaFX and Eclipse': 'Non-modular from IDE' and 'Modular from IDE'..

What's the difference between this terms?

Comment: In this context "modular" seems to be used to refer to a project declaring a module (i.e. one that contains a `module-info.java` file). I'd recommend using a "modular" project: Even though you'll need "another set of imports" there are a few issues with access that would otherwise require fixing this via command line parameters...

Comment: @fabian could you please elaborate a little bit further?  when you say that you'd need another set of imports, I assume you mean import statements within a project.  Where can this set of imports be found or identified? When you say a few issues with access, access to what exactly are you referring to? Additionally, when you say that you recommend using a modular project, is that something that needs to be specified at the time of project creation?  If so how does one specify that? Lastly, you say a modular project includes module-info.java file. How does one include such a file in a project?

Comment: not specific to javafx, basically plain java ..

Answer (score 3):

#### Introduction

The differences can be defined in many ways, I will define it to you in one way to understand the logic behind it.

#### Modular

The word **Modular** defines that modules are integrated into the project.

When you create a JavaFX project and add a class called `module-info.java` to the JavaFX project, you must add modules. Adding modules proves that the project is a modular JavaFX project.

#### Non-Modular

The word **Non-Modular** defines that no modules are integrated into the project.

If you create a JavaFX project and do not integrate a class named `module-info.java`, the project is Non-Modular because no modules are added to the JavaFX project.

> The word **Modular** and **Non-Modular** has many meanings in computer
> science, I have defined it for you as I saw the question from my point
> of view.

Comment: why do you delete and repost the same answer? Don't, instead edit the first to improve it!

Comment: I accidentally posted the answer twice and removed one answer, otherwise the answers would be marked as spam and removed by the Stackoverflow team. To make it clear for your perspective.

Comment: @AVAIDN, I unfortunately still don't get the difference, a question: When you are talking about module-info.java, is this for example a file that in gradle is "integrated" as a dependency to a "library" that your project use? In other words, what do you mean with "integrate into the project", is that a java file that you put into your project, or is it a java file that is in a library and that is (most often) already compiled when you build your project, because it is inside some java library api or whatever, but is "INTEGRATED" because it is a dependency? IOW, what is integrating a class?